# Error in TFS when move databases to SQL availability group server (TF246017)

Tags: sql-server, tfs, high-availability

I've backed up TFS databases and set them up in a SQL Server availability group and now when I try to connect to TFS I get an error "TF246017: Team Foundation Server could not connect to the database."

I'm able to query the database through management studio.

TFS management console shows TFS has adjusted the connection string to include ;MultiSubnetFailover=True so it has clearly worked out it's an availability group. But no application tiers are showing up in the box for them in management console.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up not being an availability group issue. I'd ResetOwner to the wrong user, which didn't have permission on the database.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit more to it than what you did.

> To set the MultisubnetFailover option to true in the connection string
>   for an already running deployment of TFS, use the RegisterDB command
>   of TFSConfig with the /usesqlalwayson argument. You will need to use
>   the TFSService Control Command to stop and start TFS before you can
>   set the MultisubnetFailover option. See RegisterDB Command and
>   TFSServiceControl Command.

*Ref: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/install/sql-server/use-always-on-groups*

Comment: The /usesqlalwayson isn't actually available in SQL 2015 (which I should have mentioned I was using). But thanks.